# Repeat every number in a column a specific amount of times using R code

Tags: r

I would like to create a column of numbers using R code. I want the numbers one through five to repeat 200 times in a row each, and then the number 6 to repeat 125 times in a row. How can I code this? I tried just coding

```
New <- c(1:6,each=200)
```

hoping it would just stop when it had filled all 1125 available columns. But I just get an error message instead.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `rep(1:6, c(rep(200, 5), 250))` will do it.

Comment: @Imo not what OP wants.

Comment: `rep(1:6, each = 200, length.out = 1125)` or use `length.out = nrow(your_df)`

Comment: @GR1818 You want `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ... 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 6 ...` or `1 1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 2 2 .... 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 ...`

Comment: Sounds like `c(rep(1:5, each = 200), rep(6, 125))`. Use `times` instead of `each` if you want the whole sequence repeated not each element repeated.